# How to define the type of a Binary Search Tree in Julia?

Tags: julia, union

I try to define the type of a Binary Search Tree of integers in Julia with the following :

```
mutable  struct BST
    key::Int
    left::Union{BST, Nothing}
    right::Union{BST, Nothing}
end
```

Now I would like to define the constructors and the basic Push! method using this naive approach :

```
BST(key::Int) = BST(key, Nothing, Nothing)
BST() = BST(0)

function Base.push!(node::BST, key)
    if key < node.key
        if node.left.isnull
            node.left = BST(key)
        else
            push!(node.left.value, key)
        end
    elseif key > node.key
        if node.right.isnull
            node.right = BST(key)
        else
            push!(node.right.value, key)
        end
    end
end

root = BST()
push!(root, 1)
push!(root, 2)
```

Of course it does not work with Julia 1.0 ! I certainly don't understand properly the use of union. Are they only abstract type ? What could be the correct way to define this data-structure ?

Julia documentation is poor at explaining this topic.

A previous question adressed the subject with the now deprecated Nullable type:
[How to implement a Binary Search Tree in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383517/how-to-implement-a-binary-search-tree-in-julia/52328036#52328036)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how the code should look like (it assumes that you do not want to store duplicate values in your BST, but I guess this is what you wanted):

```
BST(key::Int) = BST(key, nothing, nothing)
BST() = BST(0)

function Base.push!(node::BST, key)
    if key < node.key
        if node.left === nothing
            node.left = BST(key)
        else
            push!(node.left, key)
        end
    elseif key > node.key
        if node.right === nothing
            node.right = BST(key)
        else
            push!(node.right, key)
        end
    end
end
```

Actually your definitions were almost OK, with minor syntactic problems:

- `nothing` is a value and `Nothing` is a type so you had to write `BST(key, nothing, nothing)` not `BST(key, Nothing, Nothing)`
- you test if something is nothing using this kind of comparison `node.left === nothing` (use `===` as then compiler can optimize this code more easily)
- you had to `push!` to a `BST` object not to a value stored in it so `push!(node.right, key)` not `push!(node.right.value, key)`

Comment: Julia is elegant . Thank you.

Comment: What is more - all those bugs are caught by Julia compiler. When you have enough experience reading the error messages then it is easy to fix them. E.g. The third bug (passing `node.right.value` to `push!`) would silently be accepted by a language that does not allow to specify function argument types, and kick back in an unexpected moment.